# Named Cells Are Going Wacko, Corrupt File?

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I click in a cell, and try to rename it, I get an entirely new reference to it, and the old one doesn't delete.

This wouldn't be a problem if I could delete the old reference, but if there is something wrong with the file, this might not be the best idea.

Is there any way to delete existing name references to a cell?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: The question is "Is there any way to delete existing name references to a cell?", with some useful background provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel 2003 at least, click Insert -> Name -> Define, select the reference you no longer want and click Delete.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand your question. If you want to delete names, you can do so using VBA. A workbook has a [`names` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.names%28VS.80%29.aspx). So you can do something like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("SomeName").Delete
```

BTW, you can also delete the names manually (just in case you don't know. EDIT: see [Vicky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186416/named-cells-are-going-wacko-corrupt-file/3186781#3186781)).